# Showing convergence of $\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin{(\ln^2{x})}\frac{dx}{x}$ using Dirichlet's test

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I'm trying to prove that the following improper integral converges by Dirichlet's test: $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \sin{(\ln^2{x})}\frac{dx}{x}$$

First, let $g(x) = 1/x$. It is monotonous and tends to zero as $x\to+\infty$, which satisfies the Dirichlet's test for $g$. So then, let $f(x)=\sin{\ln^2{x}}$. Now we need to show that $F(\omega) = \int_0^\omega f(x)dx$, but I'm not sure how to do that. Or should I not use Dirichlet's test here at all?

**Addendum**: Dirichlet's test for improper integral convergence:
Let $f,g$ be defined and locally integrable on $[a,b)$. Then the integral $$\int_a^b f g \ dx$$ converges if

1. The function $$F(\omega) = \int_a^\omega f \ dx$$ is bounded on $[a,b)$
2. $g$ is monotonous and tends to zero as $x\to b-0$.

Comment: Are you sure this integral actually converges (at either endpoint)? What happens if you make the change of variables $u=\ln x^2=2\ln x$?

Comment: @GregMartin Perhaps it's supposed to be $\sin(\ln(x)^2)?$

Comment: Correct, my bad, it should be $\sin{\ln^2{x}}$

Comment: Have you tried to see what happens with Haar's measure ?

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with that, and I _should_ be able to prove this without measure theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enforcing the substitution $\log(x) \mapsto x$, we have for $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$ and $L>1$

$$\begin{align}
\int_\varepsilon^L \frac{\sin(\log^2(x))}x \,dx&=\int_{\log(\varepsilon)}^{\log(L)} \sin(x^2)\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^{-\log(\varepsilon)} \sin(x^2)\,dx+\int_0^{\log(L)} \sin(x^2)\,dx
\end{align}$$

Next, we enforce the substitution $x^2\mapsto x$ to obtain

$$\begin{align}
\int_\varepsilon^L \frac{\sin(\log^2(x))}x \,dx&=\frac12\int_0^{(\log(\varepsilon))^2} \frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt x}\,dx+\int_0^{(\log(L))^2} \frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt x}\,dx
\end{align}$$

Now apply Dirichlet's test and let $\varepsilon\to 0^+$ and $L\to \infty$.  Can you finish now?